# How can I make this code more optimized and run faster?

Tags: c#

The code below runs extremely slow when the variable c reaches around 15. I haven't seen past 16 and I need it to go all the way up to 25.

```
    public static int c = 0;
    public static void TryAll(long x, long y)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i < 10; i++)
        {
            double powered = Math.Pow(y, i);
            if (x % y == 0 && powered == x && x % 10 != 0)
            {
                c++;
                Console.WriteLine("----- {0}", c);
                Console.WriteLine(powered);
                Console.WriteLine(y);
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int baseNum = 0;
        for (c = c; c < 26; baseNum++)
        {

            if (baseNum > 9)
            {
                int sum = 0;
                int baseNumD = baseNum;
                while (baseNumD != 0)
                {
                    sum += baseNumD % 10;
                    baseNumD /= 10;
                }
                TryAll(baseNum, sum);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what does this code do ? It would be helpful before reading all of your code and try to understand what it actually does.

Comment: using `Math.Pow`  doesnt make sens ... in fact you can use `*=` instead `long powered = y;` then in loop `powered *= y;`

Comment: This question is probably better suited on [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), but you need to explain more about what the code does.

Comment: I'm trying to find numbers where the nth power of the sum of the digits of the number is equal to the number itself. If that makes sense.

Comment: Declare variables before for loops, then set them inside for loops.

Comment: `I'm trying to find numbers where the nth power of the sum of the digits of the number is equal to the number itself. If that makes sense.` Please show at least 3 examples in your question of inputs that meet that condition, and 3 that don't (and why).

Comment: @AcedPI: `81` -> `8+1=9` -> `9^2=81`... but your code outputs `81, 9, 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This will find all numbers up to `int.MaxValue` in about 70 secs. Calling `Math.Pow` is probably making your performance go down the drain and checking the remainder `%` is rather unnecessary (it actually makes it slower) if you try to find the exponents with an accumulator and good old multiplication:

```
static int SumOfDigits(int n)
{
    var current = n;
    var acc = 0;

    while (current > 0)
    {
        acc += current % 10;
        current /= 10;
    }

    return acc;
}

//Current implementation only works for positive n and b
//Easy to make it work with negative values, only need to
//perform some checks in absolute values.
static bool TryFindExponent(int n, int b, out int e)
{
    e = 0;

    if (b == 0 || n == 0)
        return false;

    //Check in abs if negative inputs are expected
    if (b == 1 &&
        n != 1)
        return false;

    var acc = 1L;

    do
    {
        e += 1;
        acc *= b;
    } while (acc < n) //check in abs if negative 
                      //numbers are expected;

    if (acc == n)
        return true;

    return false;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    for (var i = 1; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        var b = SumOfDigits(i);

        if (TryFindExponent(i, b, out var e))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} = {b}^{e}");
        }
    }

    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000.0} seconds.");
}
```

This will output in my machine:

```
1 = 1^1
2 = 2^1
3 = 3^1
4 = 4^1
5 = 5^1
6 = 6^1
7 = 7^1
8 = 8^1
9 = 9^1
81 = 9^2
512 = 8^3
2401 = 7^4
4913 = 17^3
5832 = 18^3
17576 = 26^3
19683 = 27^3
234256 = 22^4
390625 = 25^4
614656 = 28^4
1679616 = 36^4
17210368 = 28^5
34012224 = 18^6
52521875 = 35^5
60466176 = 36^5
205962976 = 46^5
612220032 = 18^7
Finished in 73,075 seconds.
```

Comment: This is close to what I want but not quite. I've optimized my code a small bit and it can output up to 612220032 = 18^7 as well. But I need to go further so I replaced int variables with longs, but as you can imagine, it would still take more than just a few minutes. If 81 is x1, 5832 x5, 614656 x10 and so on, I need to go all the way to x25.